# Unity Time for calculating session length

Tags: datetime, unity-game-engine

Is there a way of registering time when you exit a Unity application (i.e. you press play and stop the app) or perhaps when you exit a standalone build?

Using the following simple line of code, I can write to the console when my start button was pressed, so I wonder if I could do the same when the app is quit, so that the difference would be the length of the session?

```
Debug.Log("Start Button pressed @ " + DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the End of Application you can Save your Session Time. And In Start Method you can Load it From `PlayerPrefs`to use it.

Like This :

```
void OnApplicationQuit()  
{
    DateTime time = new DateTime(); 
    time.AddSeconds(Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("SessionTime",time.ToBinary().ToString());
}

void Start()
{
    DateTime time = new DateTime();
    string timeString = PlayerPrefs.SetString("SessionTime","");
    if(timeString != "")
    {
        Convert.ToInt64(timeString);       
        time = DateTime.FromBinary(time);
        Debug.Log("Previous Session Time : " + time.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can also achieve this by using `System.DateTime.Now` and storing it in some variable at start. and getting Session Time at End by subtracting saved time from `System.DateTime.Now`. I hope its Helpful :)

Comment: Thank you Umair.  This is brilliant.  Where is `PlayerPrefs.Save()` saved?  I cannot seem to find it in the project pack...  The manual says it is saved to disk, but cannot find it locally either...

Comment: I use a 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22088/i-cant-find-playerprefs-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time.realtimeSinceStartup to get the number of seconds since the application was start. Furthermore, OnApplicationQuit will be called (on any MonoBehaviour that implements it) when the application is closed. I am not completely sure it works in the editor but I think it would.

```
void OnApplicationQuit() {
    Debug.Log(Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for this. Actually, it works in the Editor mode, and in the Standalone mode, I simply write the info to file. But do you know where `PlayerPrefs.Save()` is saved? I cannot seem to find it in the project pack, nor in locations like `Application.dataPath` or `Application.persistentDataPath`. The manual says it is saved to disk, but cannot find it locally either... Where should I look?